# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter' in python 3.11.5

Tags: python, tkinter, module, python-3.11

I am using Linux Mint operating system.
So, i wanted to use the tkinter module, but somehow it doesn't work for my python 3.11.5 but works for other version??

NOTE: I already installed the tkinter package. When i did $sudo apt-get install python3-tk, it says "python3-tk is already the newest version (3.10.8-1~22.04)."

My import:

```
from tkinter import *
```

It shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kenntcky/Documents/Coding/Python/snake.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tkinter import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

Comment: whilst wildcard imports are allowed, for clarity it is best to avoid them:
[wildcard imports](https://youtu.be/EueSSAyO3K0)

Comment: you dont need to install `tkinter`. This module comes shipped with python...

Comment: And if you do install it, the it would be `python -m pip install tkinter` to install to the current version of python...

Comment: @D.L `tkinter` may not be installed alongside with `Python` in some Linux distributions and it cannot be installed by`pip`.

Comment: @kenntcky How did you install Python 3.11.5?

Comment: i installed from python official website (tar.xz file), and then extracted the file. I went to the terminal, went to the python file's directory, and did `./configure`, `make`, and then `sudo make install`. Is there something wrong when I'm installing it?

Comment: Then you need to have development packages of tcl/tk installed, otherwise `_tkinter.so` will not be built.

Comment: In Linux, use `sudo pip3 apt` not `pip`.